# Java - Convert File[] item to BufferedImage

Tags: java, file, image-processing, bufferedimage

I have an array of 300 image filenames and wish to convert each filename into a new BufferedImage.

Array of 300 image names is created thus:

```
//Default image directory (to convert to greyscale).
static File dir = new File("images");
//Array of original image filenames.
static File imgList[] = dir.listFiles();

public static void processGreyscale(){
    if(dir.isDirectory()){
        for(File img : imgList){
            if(img.isFile()){
                //functions are carried out here.
            }
            else{
                //functions are carried out here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to convert all `imgList[x]` items to `BufferedImage` items using something along the lines of:

```
File file = new File(new BufferedImage(imgList[0-300]));

try {
    image = ImageIO.read(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The 2nd bit of code doesn't make sense, and won't compile. Loop over the array of File, load each one with ImageIO - each load will return an Image...See the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) on this.

Comment: The second part won't compile because it is a theoretical piece of code of how I would like it to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below solutions will help you.

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
public class BufferedImageBuilder {

private static final int DEFAULT_IMAGE_TYPE = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;

public BufferedImage bufferImage(Image image) {
    return bufferImage(image, DEFAULT_IMAGE_TYPE);
}

public BufferedImage bufferImage(Image image, int type) {
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), type);
    Graphics2D g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, null, null);
    waitForImage(bufferedImage);
    return bufferedImage;
}

private void waitForImage(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
    final ImageLoadStatus imageLoadStatus = new ImageLoadStatus();
    bufferedImage.getHeight(new ImageObserver() {
        public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            if (infoflags == ALLBITS) {
                imageLoadStatus.heightDone = true;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    bufferedImage.getWidth(new ImageObserver() {
        public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            if (infoflags == ALLBITS) {
                imageLoadStatus.widthDone = true;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    while (!imageLoadStatus.widthDone && !imageLoadStatus.heightDone) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}

class ImageLoadStatus {

    public boolean widthDone = false;
    public boolean heightDone = false;
}
```

}